# How to implement Sepia tone in C with Native Development Kit (NDK)?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Please, someone could tell me How can I implement Sepia tone in Language C?, In my project I´ve got to implement the code with Android NDK. I´ve found some examples and I must code with this:

```
outputRed = (inputRed * .393) + (inputGreen *.769) + (inputBlue * .189)
outputGreen = (inputRed * .349) + (inputGreen *.686) + (inputBlue * .168)
outputBlue = (inputRed * .272) + (inputGreen *.534) + (inputBlue * .131)
```

Sepia toning in C#
http://www.techques.com/question/1-4141150/Convert-bitmap-to-sepia-in-android

How could I implement this code above, but NDK C, please?
I really appreciate if someone can help me or give some tips.
Regards,
Carlos

Comment: That seems like it would work fine as C code.  Can you be more specific about what exactly you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

It´s simple, I´ve got a final project and I need to implement a Android Camera app, so I need to convertir normal photo to Sepia tone, but in code native, it means in C. I´ve found some examples, but all that I find is in C# or ColorMatrix Class. There is an example:
https://bitbucket.org/steven_rudenko/colormatrix

I need to implement Sepia toning in C, but using Android NDK.

Regards,
Carlos